# print php array values with jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

The jquery script is printng `"` and `,` why?

php script:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'classes/datahandle.class.php';

$data = new Datahandle();
$query = "SELECT i.instructionValue FROM INSTRUCTION_INPUT i WHERE i.deviceId = '$_SESSION[deviceId]' AND i.instructionState = '1' ORDER BY inputPortNumber";
$inputResult = $data->selectDataQuery($query);

while ($inRow = mysql_fetch_array($inputResult)){
    $array[] = $inRow[0];
}

header("Content-type: text/plain");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

jquery script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var refreshId = setInterval(function() {  
    $.get('response.php', function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        $('#value'+index).html(value).show();
      });
    });
  }, 3000);
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false});
});
</script>

HTML:

<tbody><tr style="color: white; font-weight: bold;">
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;" id="value0">[</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;" id="value1">"</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;" id="value2">1</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;" id="value3">1</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;" id="value4">"</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;" id="value5">,</td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center; color: white; font-weight: bold;" id="value6">"</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Why the jquery isn't printing the values from the php array correctly in each html id? At the moment is printing " and , and the int's are camming separated...

Comment: @FCC-PT: Can you show explicitly what you got, and what you were expecting?

Comment: Ok maybe html helps a bit... I'm requesting some data from my database and update table with id="value0" .... id="value100" etc

Comment: Please add you current json output to the question.

Comment: @FCC-PT: I believe this reproduces your issue? http://jsfiddle.net/XQ7cX/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `$.getJSON`, which parses the JSON object retrieved from the AJAX request, instead of trying to process a raw string:

```
$.getJSON('response.php', function(data) {
```

Also, as suggested by @Rocket, you should change `header("Content-type: text/plain");` to `header("Content-type: application/json");` in `response.php`.

Here is the version without parsing JSON, which reproduces your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/XQ7cX/.

Here is the version with parsing JSON, which shows correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/XQ7cX/1/

Comment: You should also change `header("Content-type: text/plain");` to `header("Content-type: application/json");`